# Elements inside a Fixed Div mixes on browser Resize

Tags: html, css

```
<div id="mainMenu">
   <div id="Title">
       My Website
   </div>
   <div id="Login">
       Login
   </div>
</div>
```

in CSS, `#mainMenu` has `position:fixed;` with `left:0; right:0; width:100%;` `#Title` is `float:left;` `#Login` is `float:right;`

When the browser window is maximized, there's no problem, but when I resize it, the inside elements gets mixed, and when it becomes very small, the right elements gets under the left element, how can I keep the same size of the parent Div? even if I resize the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a minimum width to your `#mainMenu` that accommodates the children without repositioning them:

```css
#mainMenu {
    min-width: 600px;
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In CSS, set :

```
​#mainMenu{
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
}
#Title{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
}
#Login{
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
}
```

working fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/5pt6C/
    ​

Comment: depends on what he wants to do. If what I understood is correct the fiddle is working. Not ideal though because of fixed and absolute positionning.

Comment: try to resize the window - http://jsfiddle.net/5pt6C/1/  They're not just might cover each other, but they can completely disappear if the window is small enough..